# Unmapping boost shared memory

Tags: c++, boost, ipc, shared-memory

I have a code where the boost shared memory is used by a single writer and many readers.

The writer creates the shared memory, opens it with write permissions, and writes data to it from time to time.

Readers come and go all the time, each reader maps to the shared memory with read_only privileges, does what it does and than calls remove.

The problem seems to be that when a reader finishes doing whatever it is doing. It calls remove, however, remove deletes the shared_memory file for new readers and they cannot map to it.

My question is, how does a process detach from the shared memory, without removing it? There does not seem to be a detach functionality in the boost library.

Comment: Can you provide more details witch library are you using. Is that boost.interprocess?

Comment: Indeed. Could be Boost Interprocess or Boost Iostreams

Comment: #include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a shared refcount.

A shared shared pointer or a semaphore to achieve this.

For Boost Interprocess, closing does *not* remove the mapping/shared object. Just do not call remove.

Comment: How do I call a close? There is not close API call as far as I can see, only remove which is what causing my problem. And I do not wish to leave mapped shared memory once I'm done with it in the reader clients.

Comment: When the `shared_memory_object`, `managed_shared_memory` or `managed_mapped_file` goes out of scope it's closed. Exactly like with a `std::fstream`, really. This is C++ :)

Comment: but when it is closed is the memory unmapped on the process level, I understand that the object can get out of scope, but if the shared memory still remains mapped in the process that is problematic - and what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Yeah well. That would be a resource leak and you'd report that as a bug. Hint: no that doesn't happen. Yes: shared memory stick around until deleted. No, it doesn't remain mapped without you asking for it